# Cassandra read timeouts on AWS

Tags: cassandra

TL;DR: I'm using Cassandra. I'm making tests to see if it will handle the load but I get lots of timeouts when reading the data.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
```

I have set up a Cassandra cluster on Amazon AWS: 8 m4.xlarge instances with 2 EBS drives - type 'gp2' - of 100 GB each (commit log on one drive, the rest of the data on the other one). The instances are in the same availability zone, in a VPC. I'm using the stock version of Apache Cassandra 3.7 with no specific tuning of the servers or of Cassandra itself.

I have loaded 1 Billion records. Each of them has about 30 fields. Primary key is made of 2 partition keys and one clustering column. I have about 10 records per partition key. Replication factor is 3. Each of the 8 nodes stores about 40 GB of data after compaction.

My test consists in making 1000 queries on random keys with a basic Scala application using the Datastax Cassandra driver. The `WHERE` clause contains the partition key and I read all the records, i.e. the `WHERE` clause does not include the clustering column.

When the queries are sequential, all the queries return expected results and the average response time is 74 ms.

When I use async queries, make all the queries at once and call `get()` on the `Future`s, I get many timeouts after 5 seconds (between 25% and 75% of the queries fail).

I assumed the EBS drives might be throttled and I tried with a different cluster: 3 nodes of type i2.xlarge with data stored on the ephemeral drives.

Notice that, during my tests, the compaction had stopped doing its job. I did not see the Garbage Collector kicking in during the queries.

Any idea why the queries are generating time outs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use async queries, make all the queries at once and call get() on the Futures, I get many timeouts after 5 seconds (between 25% and 75% of the queries fail).

Did you throttle your async queries ? How many select did you send to the cluster, asynchronously ?

Comment: DuyHai is right, try not to send more than 100 queries at once and wait for their result before sending a new batch. 
You are most likely DDOSing your nodes.

Comment: I'm sending all the queries at once. It's only when all of then have been sent that I try to retrieve the results. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/aseigneurin/b11afd1247752db952f163b6f8b9b508

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks @doanduyhai and @alexander-dejanovski!